# Is it worth it to fly from Viracopos International Airport from São Paulo

Tags: airports, brazil, sao-paulo

I'm weighing my options with internal flights in Brazil, and I see cheap prices for trips coming out of **Viracopos International Airport**, which is more than an hour drive away from São Paulo, the price differs in about 50 dollars, but is it worth it?

Here is a map of the three airports, did I get this wrong? My understanding is that Viracopos is quite far.

[image]

Comment: How do you measure ‘worth it’? Time taken? Reliability? Punctuality?

Comment: Time and price,by public transport (cheaper) it takes 3 hours, by taxi, I have no idea how much it costs

Comment: Are you comparing this with Congonhas or Guarulhos? Because Guarulhos is also quite far away from the city center

Comment: Just added the map of my understanding of where the airport is, did I get this wrong?

Comment: anybody from Brazil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whom you're flying with, free or cheap airport shuttles might be available from Congonhas or Guarulhos.

Alternatively, Tiete, Barra Funda and other bus stations offer affordable shuttles to Viracopos.

Is it worth it? That depends on your time and money. If you're staying in Sao Paulo close to a place that offers an easy transfer, perhaps it is.